# Comment utiliser un dictionnaire de cooccurrences ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Utilisez-vous un dictionnaire de cooccurrences pendant vos rédactions en français ?

Comment: Je propose de fermer cette question car ni son titre ni la question proprement dite n'ont un rapport avec la langue française.

Comment: Accessoirement, je n'avais jamais entendu parler d'un tel dictionnaire donc merci quand-même pour cette question qui me fera me coucher un peu moins bête qu'au lever :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because c'est le même site qui est proposé ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32823/635 cela ressemble à du spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J'utilise souvent [Inspirassion - le dictionnaire de cooccurrences en ligne](https://inspirassion.com/fr/), ça me permet d'économiser des heures de réflexion sur le choix des mots, Il suffit de fournir une base de collocation (un mot) et de spécifier le type de collocation à extraire, le moteur se chargera ensuite d'identifier les meilleurs cooccurrences parmi des milliers de sources littéraires.

Comment: Le lien ne fonctionne pas !

Comment: Il fonctionne normalement

Comment: Certes, mais seulement depuis que cl-r l'a corrigé !

Comment: Par ailleurs, pourquoi poser une question et y répondre dans le même temps ?

Comment: @Toto C'est une manière entièrement légitime d'enrichir StackExchange

Comment: @toto ou plutôt de faire de l'auto-promotion d'un site dont on ne sait rien...